# Uformat and Unix Timestamp

Tags: powershell, timestamp

Im want to play with a date with Powershell using addMinutes() method and get my date to the Unix Timestamp format.
 I can do this to change my date:

```
$date  = (Get-Date).AddMinutes($t)
```

I can do this to get Timestamp format

```
$date  = [int]Get-Date -UFormat %s
```

But i can't manage to have the both syntax in one line. Something like

```
$date  = (Get-Date).AddMinutes($t) -uFormat %s
```

Thx for your help.

Comment: Your second line cannot work because PowerShell is not in command mode after the cast operator. You'd have to use parentheses around the `Get-Date` call (or move the `[int]` before the variable name). Besides, it cannot work generally because it fails in certain non-English locales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$date = Get-Date ((Get-Date).AddMinutes($t)) -UFormat %s
```